# Check if MySQL Column is empty

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a page, where users post their betting picks. In MySQL I have the table bets (id, event, pick, odds, stake, analysis, status, profit).

I would like to check if 'status' is empty in MySQL, but the `if()` statement is not working. If it's empty, it should output all the bets from a user. The code posted is in a for loop.

So what is wrong with the `if()` statement? And is there any better way to do this?

```
$result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM bets WHERE user='$user'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if ('' !== $row['status']) {
    echo  "Status: " . $status . "</div>" .
    "Published by: " . $user . "<br>" .
    "PICK: " . $pick . "<br>" .
    "Odds: " . $odds . "<br>" .
    "Stake: " . $stake . "<br>" .
    nl2br($analysis) ;
}
```

Comment: use mysql_num_rows()

Comment: You can use `if (!empty($row['status']))` and/or `if (!null($row['status']))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If it's **empty**, it should output all the bets from a user. The code posted is in a for loop.

Since you are checking if it's empty, your `if` statement should be the other way round:

```
if ($row['status'] == '') {
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) get the number of rows:

> Returns the number of rows in the result set.

```
$result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM bets WHERE user='$user'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo  "Status: " . $status . "</div>" .
    "Published by: " . $user . "<br>" .
    "PICK: " . $pick . "<br>" .
    "Odds: " . $odds . "<br>" .
    "Stake: " . $stake . "<br>" .
    nl2br($analysis) ;
}
```

---

Also, there isn't such function called `queryMysql()`:

```
$result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM bets WHERE user='$user'");
```

It should be `mysqli_query()`. For `mysqli_query()`, the connection parameter is needed.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM bets WHERE user='$user'");
```

Comment: $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); comes inside num_rows.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `identical` comparison, which would check for `type` & `value` both. *`===` or `!==` as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.*

Instead try -

```
if (!empty($row['status'])) { // assuming status would hold only strings (not false/0 etc)
```

Or

```
if ($row['status'] != '') {
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `mysqli_num_rows()`. If its greater then 0 then we can say that query containing result so we can further proceed.

```
$result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM bets WHERE user='$user'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  if ($row['status'] != "") {
  echo  "Status: " . $status . "</div>" .
  "Published by: " . $user . "<br>" .
  "PICK: " . $pick . "<br>" .
  "Odds: " . $odds . "<br>" .
  "Stake: " . $stake . "<br>" .
  nl2br($analysis) ;
  }
}
```

For status check you can use any of below method

```
if ($row['status'] != "") { }
```

OR

```
if (!empty($row['status'])) { }
```